# Understanding MongoDB memory usage

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I've got Django app with mongoengine, which executes some aggregation-queries often enough.

The main problem is that **mongod** takes all the RAM and then crashes, so no LRU working, **mongod** just trying to get more and more memory.

My mongodb version is 3.2 and default engine is MMAPv1. As docs says, for caching MMAPv1 needs dataSize+indexSize amount of RAM. In my case that's about 370Mb (~290 for dataSize and ~80 for indexSize).

Here is my db.stats():

```
{
    "db" : "random_db",
    "collections" : 14,
    "objects" : 155613,
    "avgObjSize" : 1859.8720672437394,
    "dataSize" : 289420272,
    "storageSize" : 338821120,
    "numExtents" : 32,
    "indexes" : 22,
    "indexSize" : 82512192,
    "fileSize" : 1006632960,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 25,
        "totalSize" : 258314240
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Actually I've got 1GB RAM and made swap-file for another 1GB.
When my app executes first aggregation query (taking only 50 documents from collection), mongod RAM usage increasing to ~300Mb (when I start service it's about 50-100Mb), and till ~70 such queries been executed - all of my memory+swap ends and **mongod** crashes.

I've created all the indexes, that needs for aggregation's '$match', if needed, I can add some of them here.

So why ~4000 documents in cache taking more than 2GB of RAM, if my entire database takes only 370Mb and there is only 150k documents in db? I know I'm doing something wrong, the question is very simple, but still I can't find explanation at docs.

BTW, here is my db.serverStatus.mem:

```
{
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 112,//this value growth when queries executed
    "virtual" : 2523,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 1136,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 2272
}
```

So, I guess, my **mongod** can't take more than 2523Mb for entire db in cache?

Comment: I'm not sure about the memory usage but if you need to get the query running then some of the following might be helpful... have you tried using the explain command to see if your query is hitting your indexes? maybe you could break your aggregation stages down by outputting the results after a certain stage to another document, also out of curiosity, I remember reading that aggregation queries are capped at 100MB so are you use the allowdiskuse option?

Comment: @iestync yes I use allowdiskuse and my indexes covers $match of aggregation queries